# Android Studio - CPU profiler .trace = "CPU usage details not available"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

How to see the graph data of the stored .trace file in Android studio. The .trace file is showing the parsed information and the graph, but when I load a stored file, its not loading the graph and is throwing an error "CPU usage details not available". Please help in retrieving the data.

[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't help but I would also like to know why is this not working. I use Android Studio 3.5.2.

I have also opened a bug report on this, you can follow it here as well.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147972089

Comment: Have you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: No. I haven't found a solution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.